# Run node function by name

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to call function from array. first part is working where i am able to call function. but unable to get return value.

```
var Handler = {};

async function iamin(field) {
    validations = ["abc", "def"];
    validations.forEach(function (element) {
        console.log(element);
       abc = Handler[element].call(field);
        return abc
    });
    return false;
}

Handler.abc = async function (field) {
    return 1;
}

Handler.def = async function (field) {
    return 2;
}

module.exports = {
    iamin
};
```

I am getting error on 
(node:48585) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Input.dispatchKeyEvent): Target closed.

Answer (score 0):

`abc = Handler[element].call(field);` This will store the result of the call function. In this case it is a promise.

Therefore if you just want to return the function you need to store the function separately:

```
var Handler = {};

async function iamin(field) {
    validations = ["abc", "def"];
    return validations.map(async function (element) {
        const abc = Handler[element];
        const value = await abc.call(field);
        // console.log(value);
        console.log(abc);
        return abc;
    });
}

Handler.abc = async function (field) {
    return 1;
}

Handler.def = async function (field) {
    return 2;
}
iamin(1).then( res => console.log(res));


module.exports = {
    iamin
};
```

Comment: your code working as it is. but for some reason i am not able to access field in function abc.
`field = await page.$(emailInput);`

Comment: `Handler.abc = async function (field) {
    return field;
}
` returns undefined